# SPARQL for changing multiple URIs

Tags: sparql

I have over a thousand URIs which have an incorrect value inside, I want to know if theres a way on changing it to the correct value.

I have tried the following CONSTRUCT

```
INSERT {
    ?s ?p <http://example.co.uk/2017-19/HL13015>  .
}

 WHERE {

       <http://example.co.uk/2017-19%20(57)/HL13015> rdf:type "exWP" .
       ?s ?p <http://example.co.uk/2017-19%20(57)/HL13015> .

}
```

it worked for that particular record but i want to do it for multiple. Is there a way where we can part of the URI and then delete the incorrect part and insert the correct part?

Comment: You can use a filter with a `REGEX` to find the resource (aka URIs) that match a specific pattern. Then you can also use `replace` function to replace a part of those URIs, i.e. `BIND(IRI(REPLACE(...)) as ?newURI)` and use this in the `INSERT` part

Comment: by the way, your sample query doesn't make sense, or at least, I have never seen a string literal like `"exWP"` used as value of the property `rdf:type` - don't do this, it's just wrong!

Comment: the rdf:type should have the object value exWP:Wpq i can't put the correct value in this thread as its sensitive data. Thanks for your response

Comment: Ok, at least you got the idea how to change multiple URIs. Please provide the answer once you have the final query.

Comment: Presumably, you want to DELETE the old values as well?

Comment: Sometimes, it's easier to dump the data to a text file and use text editing tools to fix up URIs.

Comment: Interesting i didnt know you could, how would you do that? i want to DELETE the old values 2017-19%20(57) and replace with 2017-19 only

Comment: I would like to retain the graph triples, there are 3 graphs any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone landing here, this is an update query that will swap both `subject` and `object` items from `?oldIRI` to an updated `?newIRI` in SparQL:

```
WITH <named-graph-iri> # optional if using default graph
DELETE {
  ?oldIRI ?p1 ?o1 .
  ?s2 ?p2 ?oldIRI .
}
INSERT {
  ?newIRI ?p1 ?o1 .
  ?s2 ?p2 ?newIRI .
}
WHERE {
  VALUES ?oldIRI { <http://example.co.uk/2017-19%20(57)/HL13015> }
  VALUES ?newIRI { <http://example.co.uk/2017-19/HL13015> }
  
  { ?oldIRI ?p1 ?o1 }
  UNION { ?s2 ?p2 ?oldIRI }
}
```